# POSIXct type demoting on Apache Spark 2.1.0 with SparkR dapply

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I have an issue with SparkR (Apache Spark 2.1.0) apply functions. When applying any function over a SparkDataFrame, timestamps in POSIXct type get demoted to integer, as POSIXct is saved as an integer milliseconds since Epoch.

Is there any way to prevent this simplification?

Here is a minimal example:

I create an R data.frame and load in into Spark:

```
localDF <- data.frame(time=as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-01 00:51:45","2016-01-01 02:29:51", "2016-01-01 03:58:45", "2016-01-01 05:27:23")))
df <- as.DataFrame(localDF)
str(df)
```

The output obtained is:

```
'SparkDataFrame': 1 variables:
 $ time: POSIXct 2016-01-01 00:51:45 2016-01-01 02:29:51 2016-01-01 03:58:45 2016-01-01 05:27:23
```

Now I use dapply for applying an R function over this SparkDataFrame:

```
sillyFunction <- function(x){   
    return(x)
}
outdf <- dapplyCollect(df, sillyFunction)
str(outdf)
```

However, the structure is changed:

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ time: num  1.45e+09 1.45e+09 1.45e+09 1.45e+09
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sparkr.html#gapply), I understand that the mapping between POSIXct in R to timestamp in Spark is done by default.

However, you can read it back with your original POSIXct format with a little modification of your function.

```
sillyFunction <- function(x){
  return(strftime(as.POSIXct(x$time, origin="1970-01-01"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
}

> outdf <- dapplyCollect(df, sillyFunction)
> str(outdf)
 chr [1, 1:4] "2016-01-01 00:51:45" "2016-01-01 02:29:51" "2016-01-01 03:58:45" "2016-01-01 05:27:23"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I had already considered an approach like yours, the problem is that I don't want to cast timestamp to POSIXct each time I need to use it.  I'm now considering using directly epoch timestamp in seconds so that I can do most of the operations, but if the data is set to a given schema, why does SparkR demote it?